# How can I control the power through a resistive load

Tags: power-electronics, control-system, resistive-load

I have a project where I need to control the power through a resistive load.

The project consists of controlling the temperature on the outlet of a pipe, the inlet will flow at a velocity of 2.2m/s and will always have a temperature lower than the outlet. I am working with a 5cm diameter pipe.

To heat up the air flowing, A resistive load with 100W AC will be placed in the middle of the piping. That means a resistor that dissipates 100W when connected to AC line. I will use a tolerance of 1ºC, and expect the temperature set point to be between 25ºC and 35ºC. It has to correct the temperature in 5s.

I am not sure how to control the power flowing in the load, I thought of using a converter and controlling the transistor and maybe using a capacitive filter.

However, I don't have much experience with power electronics and would appreciate any suggestions on this.

Thanks.

Comment: This is just a heater? Are you sure you *need* to control the power?

Comment: I must set a specific outlet temperature, the inlet may vary

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to give enough information to answer.  The important points are: What do you mean by "resistive load with 100W AC" -- do you mean a resistor that _would_ dissipate 100W if connected to the line AC voltage?  How accurately do you need to control the output temperature?  How much temperature rise do you see at your airflow and the resistive load dissipating 100W?  How rapidly will the inlet temperature vary, and do you need to maintain outlet temperature within specifications during rapid inlet temperature changes?  We may have more questions when you finish editing.

Comment: What is the input temperature of the air?  Why are you assuming 100W is needed since 2.2m/s is fast, which means not much time to heat the air?

Comment: Frankly your heater size sounds quite inadequate. At STP you would get maybe 1.5°C rise if heat transfer was perfect (and it won't be).

Comment: I used [this](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/air-heating-systems-d_1136.html) equation to find the power, based on the parameters I have.

Comment: A typical approach would be to use PWM on the heating element and use PID to control the duty cycle.  I am so bogged down by other concerns with this design, however, so I can't really answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your flow rate (2.2 m/s) means that the contact with the heater
will be less than a second?   There will be nonuniform temperatures
in the flow if the heater doesn't have thermal mass enough to
'filter' those fluctuations (and that means the electrical bits
don't need any filter components, like a capacitor).

Probably a good heat exchanger (heatsink-like fins) mounted
to a heated brick would satisfy the need for low temperature
rate-of-change.

A thermostat control that monitors air outlet temperature and switches
AC power on and off would complete the design.   Such controls
have hysteresis (they switch ON at temperature T1, when temperature
drops, but switch OFF at temperature T2, when temperature rises),
so you can select two switch points (like, 28C = T1, 32C = T2).

Not knowing the incoming air temperature, one '100W' heater
might not suffice, but that situation can be remedied by putting
two or more thermostat-heaters in series.